# An exercise on implication (proof and logic)

Tags: logic, proof-verification

This question is derived from the book "How to think like a Mathematician" which does not have solutions to its questions.

Following exercise is on implications:

Suppose that students were told that on each side of a card was an alphabet and on the other was a number. The students are shown the following four cards with alphabets or numbers on one side:

$$A \quad J \quad 3 \quad 8$$

The task was to decide whether the rule 'If a card has an alphabet on one side, then it has an even number on the other side' was true or not. The students had to turn only the cards which had to be turned over to judge the correctness of the rule.

Which cards in the above example would you turn over and which would you not? Justify your answers.

[Edit: You may refer to https://books.google.com.my/books?id=T7iSt1Vzc-4C&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=suppose+that+students+were+told+that+on+each+side+of+a+card+was+a+vowel&source=bl&ots=AL6q3Zt2r_&sig=i_umHgCZaz_T5e788qR6p7OzcV8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false question (v) for the original question]

My solution is following:

We note that the rule is: **vowel on one side only if even number on the other side**. The contrapositive is **odd number on one side only if not vowel on the other side.**

To show that the rule is correct by picking the correct cards, I would pick the second card (with a J) and the fourth card (with an 8).

If I pick the first card (with an A), and it happens that the other side is an odd number, it would void the rule.

If I pick the third card and the other side turns out to be a vowel, this violates the contrapositive version of the rule.

By picking the second and the forth card, the rule "**Vowel on one side only if even number on the other side**" would be true vacuously.

Anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: The problem makes no sense as posed. I suspect that you meant: "Suppose that students were told that on each side of a card was a letter and on the other was a number. The students are shown the following four cards with letters or numbers on one side"?

Comment: So which cards would you turn over?

Comment: @joriki: I even didn't notice and intepreted it as you suppose. :-)

Comment: @joriki you may refer to the link https://books.google.com.my/books?id=T7iSt1Vzc-4C&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=suppose+that+students+were+told+that+on+each+side+of+a+card+was+a+vowel&source=bl&ots=AL6q3Zt2r_&sig=i_umHgCZaz_T5e788qR6p7OzcV8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

question number (v). Yes for some reason I also interpreted as letter instead of vowel when I looked at the question.

Comment: @Daniel: Well, I guess it's either a trick question or a typo. The card with a J on it obviously doesn't fit that description of the cards.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly solved the task of turning over only cards for which you're sure the rule will be fulfilled. That's the exact opposite of the task that was set: "to decide whether the rule [...] was true or not". To do that, you have to turn over precisely the other cards, those for which you don't know yet whether they satisfy the rule.

Comment: If I flipped 'A', then the other side could be an odd or even number. Doesn't this mean that this rule could be either false or true?

Comment: @Daniel: That is why are you turning it over. That's your task to determine whether the rule is true, and since it is possible that there is an odd number on the other side of 'A', you have to check it.